# Match text in table and click on it using selenium webdriver

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have one table in which there is one column called "state". I have to find and click on link which matches with text "closed successful" in that column. xpath for each cell in that column is

```
 "//*[@id='TicketID_xxxxxx']/td[7]/div
```

Where xxxxxx are numbers of tickets. So how can I find matching text with different xpath values and click on it using selenium webdriver. Please help.

(Optional- I have to click on that element, click on back and find next element with same matching text)

Comment: Please add some HTML so that people can help you with that. What language binding are you using with Selenium ?

Comment: Which part of HTML should i add, and i am using java with selenium

Comment: Some example of the table you're trying to process, a few rows.

Comment: It is 7th row, and column called state with different values like "new", "open", "closed successful". i have to match text "closed successful" and click on it. i have mentioned xpath of column cells.

Comment: why do you write td[7] but say about 7th row?

Comment: which id (id='TicketID) ? is that id of row, column, cell?

Comment: This is rubbish. Put some bloody clear HTML so we can properly evaluate and help you or close the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi  Sanket Patel please do it like below

```
driver.get(yourWebPageLInk); // link to your web-table web page

    // take all of the element under Column "State" inside list

    List<WebElement> columVal =  driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@id,'TicketID_')]/td[7]/div"));
    // count the size of the list to match with the size of the column state
    System.out.println("Size of the contents in the column state is : " +columVal.size());

    // now for matching one of the content and then performing some action please
    // start a for loop

    String oneVal = "closed successful";
    for(int i=0;i<columVal.size();i++){
        System.out.println("Content text is : " + columVal.get(i).getText());
        // match the content here in the if loop
        if(columVal.get(i).getText().equals(oneVal)){
            // perform action
            columVal.get(i).click();
        }
    }
```

Comment: i am glad it helped you please mark it as your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `text()` method

```
String text = "someText";
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), '" + text + "')]")).click();
```

Or with `cssSelector`

```
String text = "someText";
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div:contains('" + text + "')")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TableDriver extension to Selenium WebDriver for situations like this.  (https://github.com/jkindwall/TableDriver.Java).  It would be helpful if there was more detailed info about the table in question, however if we assume that the table has a column "link" containing the link you need to click, and we assume the id of the main table element is "tabelId" you could do it like this:

```java
Table table = Table.create(driver.findElement(By.id("tableId"));
WebElement element = table.findCell("state=closed successful", "link").Element;
element.findElement(By.tagName("a")).Click();
```